# Read specific part of buffer in C

Tags: c, linux, string, buffer

I have a buffer staffed with the following text in c:

```
POST /home/alex/p2download HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1767
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:1767/home/alex/p2download
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 11

pattern=*.c
```

All i want is to take only the pattern. In that example only "*.c"
How can i do it?

Comment: strstr might be good to look at.

Comment: Learn C would be a good point to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
char *pCh;
char *pattern = "pattern=";

pCh = strstr(buffer, pattern);
if(pCh)
    pCh += strlen(pattern);
```

Assuming buffer contains the text you provided, `pCh` will point to the `'*'` in `*.c`.

Answer (score 0):

You first want to find the position of your tag word in your text, to do so you can use `const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );` that will return the address of the first occurrence of `str2` in `str1`.

You can then extract the content of your http POST content in a new variable using various C *str functions as followed,

```
char* src = getYourHttpMessage();
char tag[] = "pattern=";

char* pattern_start = strstr(src, tag);

char* to_extract = NULL;
int to_extract_length = 0;

if(pattern_start != NULL) { // found the pattern
    for(to_extract = pattern_start + sizeof(tag); *to_extract != '\n'; to_extract++, to_extract_length++);
    to_extract = malloc(length_to_extract);
    strncpy(to_extract, pattern_start+sizeof(tag), to_extract_length);
}
```